# high performance computing cluster setup

Tags: cluster, mpi, high-performance

In my lab, we have several servers used for the simulation programs, but they worked independently. Now I want to combine them to become a cluster using MPICH to make them communicate. But there exists a problem, which is that these servers have different OSs. Some of them are Redhat, and some of them are Ubuntu. And on the homepage of MPICH, I saw that download sites of these two different operating systems are different, so will it be possible to set up a cluster with different operating system? And how to do it?

The reason why I don't want to reinstall these servers is that there are too many data on them and they are under used when I ask this question.

Comment: It should be possible nowadays with a container like solution. Maybe best for HPC workflow is [singularity](http://singularity.lbl.gov), but never tested it in a mixed environment. You also should carefully weigh the pros and cons of running different distros on the hosts. You add another complexity layer and also have to take care of updates, fixes and workarounds of different distributions which brings additional work.

Comment: @Thomas a container like solution? Could I take it as something like docker?